# Call a function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 3 divs (`#Mask #Intro #Container`) so if you click on Mask, Intro gets hidden and Container appears.
The problem is that I just want to load this only one time, not every time I refresh the page or anytime I click on the menu or a link, etc.

How can I do this?

This is the script I'm using for now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#mask").click(function() {
        $("div#intro").fadeToggle('slow');
        $("div#container").fadeToggle('slow');
        $("div#mask").css("z-index", "-99");
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using cookies? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 8):

You can try using a simple counter.

```
// count how many times click event is triggered
var eventsFired = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#mask").click(function() {
        if (eventsFired == 0) {
            $("div#intro").fadeToggle('slow');
            $("div#container").fadeToggle('slow');
            $("div#mask").css("z-index", "-99");
            eventsFired++; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload
        }
    });
});
```

To *persist* this you will need to [set a cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).  (e.g. `$.cookie()` if you use that plugin).

```
// example using $.cookie plugin
var eventsFired = ($.cookie('eventsFired') != null)
    ? $.cookie('eventsFired')
    : 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#mask").click(function() {
        if (eventsFired == 0) {
            $("div#intro").fadeToggle('slow');
            $("div#container").fadeToggle('slow');
            $("div#mask").css("z-index", "-99");
            eventsFired++; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload
            $.cookie('eventsFired', eventsFired);
        }
    });
});
```

To delete the cookie later on:

```
$.cookie('eventsFired', null);
```

Comment: This would not work across page refreshes (which I think is what the OP wants, not sure though...).

Comment: @FelixKling You're right, that's why I added the bit about cookies. I _was_ going to link to the jQuery plugins page but it is currently down :S.  Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!
Could you recommend some cookie plugin, please?

Comment: You're welcome! That _is_ a plugin (`$.cookie`). Here it is again though: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 5):

Just point to an empty function once it has been called.

```
var myFunc = function(){
     myFunc = function(){}; // kill it
     console.log('Done once!'); // your stuff here
};
```

Comment: I was attempting to do this with an unnamed function, which takes alot more lines as you need to close over the implicit state. Think this is about as simple as it can get.

Answer (score 1):

Web pages are *stateless* in that they don't hold states between page refreshes. When you reload the page it has no clue what has happened in the past.

Cookies to the rescue! You can [use Javascript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) (and [jQuery has some nice plugins](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/) to make it easier) to store variables on the client's browser. Store a cookie when the mask is clicked, so that when the page is next loaded it never shows.

Answer (score 0):

this code with will work perfect for you and it is the standard way provided by jquery to bind events that you want to execute only once

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div#mask").one('click', function() {
            $("div#intro").fadeToggle('slow');
            $("div#container").fadeToggle('slow');
            $("div#mask").css("z-index", "-99");
        });
    });
```