# run jQuery function only ONCE (instead of endless loop when event occur)

Tags: jquery, function, scroll, alert, scrolltop

I have this jQuery code that fires when user scroll down to the point of ad class height (and after). The problem is that I want it to run only ONCE and stop alert. Very simple tweak (and without settimeout nor setting a variable ;)

css:

```
header{width:100%;height:200px;background:teal;}
.ad{width:500px;height:120px;margin:0 auto;background:red;}
article{width:100%;height:1500px;background:yellow;}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class='ad'></div>
  </header>
  <article></article>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery :

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var aTop = $('.ad').height();
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop){
        alert('header just passed.');
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429020/call-a-function-only-once

Comment: no duplicate... different meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/hamoom/qX6bn/

```
$(function(){

var alerted = false; 

$(window).scroll(function(){
var aTop = $('.ad').height();

if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop && !alerted){
    alerted = true;
    alert('header just passed.');
} 
else if($(this).scrollTop()<=aTop && alerted){
    alerted = false;
}
});
});
```

i just use a flag to prevent it firing that alert over and over.  i reset it in the "else" block so that when you scroll back up you can get the same alert again

Comment: Try to scroll up and down you will still get additional alert(S)... http://jsfiddle.net/qX6bn/1/

Comment: And I thought that there is a cleaner method without using an external variable :D

Comment: just remove else block if you dont want additional alerts..  sometimes you have to use some extra variables.  that function is still scrolling as you get the first alert.. gotta stop it somehow

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  var alerted = false; 

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var aTop = $('.ad').height();

    if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop && !alerted){
        alerted = true;
        alert('header just passed.');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**you should use `on` and `off`** like so:

```
$(window).on('scroll.foo', function(){
    // stop this once and for all!
    if( something == true )
       $(window).off('scroll.foo');
});
```

As shown above, one must use scopes when binding events, so they could later be unbinded, without causing any damage to an exact event which might also be binded to the same object (*in this case, the window object*).

Once a certain condition has been met, the listener will cease to exist, therefor no callback will be fired.