# Run the function just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following function which is excuted twice,there is option to do it just once?
Tried many things, however, without any sucess ;(

```
$("#myDiv1, #myDiv2").fadeIn('20',function(){
    {
        alert('alert');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you link working example in fiddle.

Comment: here's how - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23684530/104380 shame on you you didn't search google or here, it has been asked countless times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **promise** to solve multiple callbacks problem:

```
$("#myDiv1, #myDiv2").fadeIn('200').promise().done(function()
{
    console.log('Test');
});
```

The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$("#myDiv1, #myDiv2").fadeIn(20).promise().done(function(){
 alert('alert');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both `#myDiv1` and `#myDiv2` in your DOM it would run twice. There's no way around it (except using `promise()` as suggested by other answers). You will just have to change your selector to something like `$('#myDiv1')`.

An alternative would be using a flag ([JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77L0bo7y/))

```
var do_run = true;

$('#myDiv1, #myDiv2').fadeIn(20, function() {
    if (! do_run) return;
    do_run = false;

    alert(2)   
})
```